# Output a string to a textfield javafx using scenebuilder

Tags: java, javafx, output, textfield, scenebuilder

Im trying to fill in a textfield with a string depending on what i wrote in another textfield. Is there a way to output a string to a textfield? Oh and im using scenebuilder.

Comment: Manually edit your FXML to use an [expression binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding) (e.g. `<TextField fx:id="sourceField" text="xyzzy"/><TextField fx:id="cloneField" editable="false" text="${sourceField.text}" />`) or [do the binding in code in your initialize method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm).  SceneBuilder will display the bound value if you bind via an expression in FXML, but not from code (doing the binding in code is more flexible though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextField inherits both the `getText()` and `setText()` methods from TextInputControl.

You could try something like:

```
textFieldToSet.setText(textFieldContainingString.getText());
```

In this case, you would be setting the text of `textFieldToSet` to whatever String is currently contained within `textFieldContainingString`.